# Test case for react using Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am new to jest test cases, I have written a code for a component and written the test cases for the same. But getting an error in mocking data. any help on this would really be helpful

this is code

```
import Router from 'next/router';

import { checkIfAbsoluteUrl } from '../../../utilities/helper/helperMethods';

import { setDataOnLinkClick } from '../footer.omniture';

export const linkClickHandler = (url = '', event) => {
    if (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (checkIfAbsoluteUrl(url)) {
        window.open(url);
    } else if (url) {
        Router.push(url);
    }
};


export const socialLinksClick = (url, tag) => {

    setDataOnLinkClick(tag);

    linkClickHandler(url);
};

export const resetPosition = (position, place) => {
    const { top, left } = position;

    switch (place) {
        case 'left': {
            return {
                top,
                left: left - 8
            };
        }
        default: {
            return {
                top,
                left
            };
        }
    }
};
```

and this is my test case

```
import { linkClickHandler } from '../utils/helperMethods';

import Router from 'next/router';

describe('Testing Helper Method', () => {
    it('link test', () => {
        const event = {
            stopPropagation: jest.fn()
        };

        linkClickHandler('', event);
        expect(event.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('Testing Absolute url', () => {
        const mockFn = jest.fn();
        mockFn();
        const url = {
            checkIfAbsoluteUrl: jest.fn()
        };

        linkClickHandler('https://www.freecharge.in/');
        expect(window.open()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('Testing  url', () => {
        const url = {
            checkIfAbsoluteUrl: jest.fn()
        };

        linkClickHandler('/paylater');
        expect(Router.push()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

when I run the above test case it is failing, showing error

expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined
```

Thank you in advance.